# filter on the_content stopped working when I updated to WP 3.6.1

Tags: filters, the-content

I created a filter to add a pin button on to my blog posts' images, which after much playing worked. Then, a few weeks later, I updated to 3.6.1, and the filter stopped working.

Did something change in the new release that would prevent filters on the_content from working?

```
function cd_insert_pinterest($content) {
        global $post;
        $postID = $post->ID;
           if( is_singular() && is_main_query() ) {
                $posturl = urlencode(get_permalink()); //Get the post URL
                $pindiv = '<span class="pinterest-button">';
                $pinurl = '<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$posturl.'&media=';
                $pindescription = '&description='.urlencode(get_the_title());
                $pinfinish = '" class="pinning"></a>';
                $pinend = '</span>';
                $pattern = '/<img(.*?)src="(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)" (.*?) width="(.*?)" height="(.*?)" \/>/i';
                $replacement = $pindiv.$pinurl.'$2.$3'.$pindescription.$pinfinish.'<img$1src="$2.$3" $4 width="$5" height="$6" />'.$pinend;
                $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );
                $newpattern = '/<a(.*?)><span class="pinterest-button"><a(.*?)><\/a><img(.*?)\/><\/span><\/a>/i';
                $replacement = '<span class="pinterest-button"><a$2></a><a$1><img$3\/></a></span>';
                $content = preg_replace( $newpattern, $replacement, $content );
           }
                                return $content;

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'cd_insert_pinterest');
```

Comment: Laurie, please don't link to outside sources. Always put every link and line of code into the question. Thanks.

Comment: oh, sorry... other posts indicated i should use pastebin for code. :)  also, I've gone through the WP support forum, the codex, and Googled extensively, and I'm not seeing anything that would indicate something has changed, but nothing I've tried is making it trigger this new code in my posts...

Comment: If you put `return 'Howdy';` as the first line in your function, what happens? Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? Also, the SE network as a whole, as far as I know, frowns on posting code externally, and for it is worth I much prefer code to be inline the way the network prefers (but I wish the formatting had line numbers).

Comment: Adding `return 'Howdy';` replaces the_content with the word 'Howdy'. The other filters/functions in this file also work as expected, just this one isn't (it's first, so the others that work are below it), and with debugging on, no errors are being displayed.

Comment: Try switching to the default theme WITH all plugins deactivated.

Comment: The function is in my theme file, so switching to another theme wouldn't help. Also, there are no plugins activated. The only thing that changed from when this function was working is I updated WP.

Comment: well if adding `return 'Howdy';` worked, then the filter is being triggered, now repeat that for each line in your function to figure out where it's failing- put it inside your `if` condition, see if that's being met, if so then `return $posturl` after that's set to make sure it's what you expect, etc., until you find the offending line.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an issue with your RegEx pattern matching images.

I modified `$pattern` to the following and it worked on a test page I setup.

```
$pattern = '/<img(.*?)src="(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)"(.*?)width="(.*?)" height="(.*?)" \/>/i';
```

There were some extra spaces which were throwing it off.

I suggest using a RegEx tester to help you make sure your pattern is correctly matching your content coming out of wordpress. This is the one I used to check your pattern:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

On a separate note, in general it's a bit hard to tell what you're trying to achieve with the two preg_replace functions. I'm sure it could be significantly simplified...